# WordPress - jQuery function to multiple elements with same class/id

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

The code below is adding a placeholder to my #e_newsletter_email div. However I have added an additional signup box for the e-newsletter and the placeholder is not showing up on the second one. Is there a way to apply this code to work on both signup boxes?

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#e_newsletter_email').attr( 'placeholder', 'You Email Address' );
});
```

I have tried to add this code to to force the id to add a class but again this only works on the first id. Any other thoughts?

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#e_newsletter_email').addClass('e_newsletter_email');
});
```

Thanks

Comment: ID's should be unique to each element - using an ID as the jQuery selector will only affect one element, as jQuery (as it should) assumes there *is* only one element with that ID. Doing this same command with a class name should work fine. The ID Selector page of the jQuery documentation states `Description: Selects a single element with the given id attribute.`

Comment: Use the "class" attribute for selector, given to these 2 elements, like `$('.newsletter_email_class').attr('placeholder', 'Your text');`

Comment: I am using a plugin that is auto generating the ID. I cannot edit it. Is there a way I can use jquery to add a class to this ID?

Comment: @mark.hch Any thoughts on this? or possible some better insight? Thanks

Comment: @Vyacheslav Any other thoughts or insight?

Comment: Thoughts would be to change the plugin to only add one unique ID per element... Are all the elements generated by the plugin? Are there options with the plugin? If the entire HTML is generated by plugin, and you can't modify it, then you could potentially use a more general selector, like `input`, loop through each to see if the ID is the one in question, and add a class that way `$('input').each(function() { if($(this).attr('id') == 'e_newsletter_email') { $(this).addClass('e_newsletter_email'); } });` it may be better though to look at writing the code yourself instead of using a plugin.

Comment: @mark.hch Yes all the elements are generated by the plugin. No options with the plugin. The plugin developer gave me the first js code I shared above. The code you just shared is giving me syntax errors, I tried to debug but was unsuccessful.

Comment: @William Can you post some of the HTML?

Comment: @mark.hch the site is http://pwc.wjmediadesign.com/ You can see I am trying to add a placeholder to both signup forms.

Comment: So close! You just need an additional `});` since you are using `jQuery(function($){` as you are currently not closing that function. So all in all, that line would be: `jQuery(function($) {
 $('input').each(function() { if($(this).attr('id') == 'e_newsletter_email') { $(this).addClass('e_newsletter_email_custom');
 } });});`

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: @William Awesome. Glad to be of help. I made my comment into an answer, so if you're looking for some karma, you could mark it as correct. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some help from @mark.hch we where able to figure out how to create a workaround. Below is the final code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(function($) { 
 $('input').each(function() { if($(this).attr('id') == 'e_newsletter_email') { $(this).addClass('e_newsletter_email_custom'); } });
});

jQuery(function($) {
  $('.e_newsletter_email_custom').attr( 'placeholder', 'You Email Address' );
});

</script>
```

First we needed to loop through each id and add a new class to the e_newsletter_email (which was being used twice). Then once we added the class to the id we where able to update the original function to use class instead of id and everything worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

An Id can only be used once. Use classes for elements that do not need to be uniquely identified.

Comment: I am using a plugin that is auto generating the ID. I cannot edit it. Is there a way I can use jquery to add a class to this ID? I have made a slight edit to my question.

Answer (score 0):

The true answer to the question is to use a class instead of an ID for both fields. As mentioned in the comments, an ID should be unique to each element on a page. In this case, however, the elements only contained an ID and the question then becomes how to add a class to the elements so a future selector can grab them all (or both) to manipulate them.

Using the ID selector `$('#e_newsletter_email')` only selects one element (as jQuery assumes there is only one element with that ID). So we need a more general selector - in this case, both elements are inputs, so the selector `$('input')` should grab at least those elements.

Since there could be more inputs on the page than the ones in question, we then need to filter out the ones we want; in this case, we compare the ID attribute of the elements (since we know, even though they're supposed to be unique, two actually contain the same ID).

Grabbing the ID of the element will work even if there are multiple elements with the same ID (`$(this).attr('id')` will always display the element's assigned ID, even if not unique).

So the code becomes:

```
//loop through all inputs
$('input').each(function() {
  //if the input currently iterating over has the ID in question
  if$(this).attr('id') == 'e_newsletter_email') {
    //add the class for the input
    $(this).addClass('e_newsletter_email_custom');
  }
});
```